# Some floating items are not re-sizing appropriately (CSS / XHTML)

Tags: html, css, resize, xhtml, css-float

So, I am using XHTML and CSS for a school assignment.

I have used the float css property in numerous places for the main layout of the page. When re-sizing the browser, **only some of the items re-size properly**.

I have referenced W3Schools.com for hours and hours and messed around with various coding samples from there with no luck to solving my problem.

I have the header at the top (which has a container [header] then then two seperate divs inside [leftHeader and rightHeader]). The right header does not seem to re-size properly (even in the JSFiddle sample you can't even see it).

**The other issue is** with the main container which consists of [main] as the container div to hold all the main content and then two other items inside [photograph] and [summary]. [Photograph] and [summary] do not re-size appropriately within [main] and [summary] overlaps the footer.

The [footer] and [navbar] seem to re-size just fine from what I can tell.

Any help as to why this is occurring, what I am doing wrong, and a possible solution would be greatly appreciated!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0mjezprv/

```
            <title>Assignment #1</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
    <div id="header">
<div id="leftHeader">
    <p class="header">
        Class (Semester 2016)<br/>
        Professor Name Here<br/>
        George Mason University
    </p>
</div>
<div id="rightHeader">
    <p class="header">
        Name Here<br/>
        <a href="mailto:kzuiker3@gmu.edu">email@gmu.edu</a><br/>
        <strong>Last Modified: </strong><em>Time Date Zone</em>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
            <div id="navBar">
        <strong>Assignments</strong>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Assignment1/">Assignment 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Assignment2/">Assignment 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="Assignment3/">Assignment 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="Assignment4/">Assignment 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
        <strong>Lab Practica</strong>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Practicum1">Practicum 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Practicum2">Practicum 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p class="footer">
        This web site is entirely orginal work therefore full academic copyright is retained. This web site complies with the <a href="honor_code_website">Mason Honor Code</a>.</p>
    </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <div id="photograph">
                    <img src="Personal_Picture.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:300px;height:240px;" />
                </div>
                <div id="summary">
                <p class="summaryText">
                    <strong>Summary</strong></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>Personal</strong>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Hobby</li>
                                <li>Hobby</li>
                                <li>Hobby</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><strong>Academic</strong>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Information Technology major</li>
                                <li>3.92 GPA</li>
                                <li>Senior standing</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="mainText" style="text-align: right;padding:3px 50px 0px 50px;"><strong>Professional &amp; Personal Details</strong></p>
            <p style="padding:0px 50px 5px 400px;">
                Personal information here
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Which of the elements resize "properly" and which ones don't? We can't read your mind, so we don't know what you consider proper. Please indicate the elements that come out wrong and tell us how they should have come out instead.

Comment: I actually mentioned most of it in the original post, "The [footer] and [navbar] seem to re-size just fine from what I can tell." The [left header] also seems to re-size okay. The [main] which also consists of [photograph] and [summary] there seems to be some issue. [photograph] seems to re-size fine, but [summary] overlaps the footer.

[summary] should stay with the [main] div, and not overlap the [footer]. The [right header] should stay positioned next to the [left header] and not disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right header isn't visible because the borders on [leftHeader] and [rightHeader] are causing the size of both elements to be over 50%.

The easiest way to correct this is to use the calc() function in the width declaration

```
.example {
    width: calc(50%  - 3px)
}
```

The above sets the width to 50% of the screen or container then reduces it by 3px in size to allow for the borders.

[photograph], [summary] and [main] won't re-size as you have given these a fixed size rather than a relative size. As your screen gets smaller these just take up more space rather than adjusting. This is why [footer] is overlapping so it can sit in its designated position.

I've provided a fix below for the navigation and headers to sit and size correctly. This should help guide you through fixing the rest of the issues as well.

```css
    #header{
        position: fixed;
        width:calc(100% - 206px);
        height: 100px;
        float:left;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        border: solid 3px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #leftHeader{
    
        width:calc(50% - 3px);
        height: 100%;
        display:inline-block;
        border-right: solid 2px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #rightHeader{
        width:calc(50% - 3px);
        height: 100%;
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #navBar {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 197px;
        border: solid 3px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
    <strong>Assignments</strong>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Assignment1/">Assignment 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Assignment2/">Assignment 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Assignment3/">Assignment 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="Assignment4/">Assignment 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <strong>Lab Practica</strong>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Practicum1">Practicum 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Practicum2">Practicum 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="header">
    <div id="leftHeader">
        <p class="header">
            Class (Semester 2016)<br/>
            Professor Name Here<br/>
            George Mason University
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightHeader">
        <p class="header">
            Name Here<br/>
            <a href="mailto:email3@gmu.edu">email@gmu.edu</a><br/>
            <strong>Last Modified: </strong><em>Time Date Zone</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sakaratte.

Can you explain why you used 206px in this statement:     |
width: calc(100% - 206px);

The navbar was 197px, so why wouldn't we subtract 197px?

Comment: its for the same reason as to why I have used - 3px in my example calc(). Instead of one border to compensate for we have 3 borders to compensate for as well as the actual length of the navbar. 

So in long form it would be calc(100% - (197px+3px*3=206)).

Comment: Okay, I understand.

Can you help me out with the [main] content? I have changed them to relative and have continued to alter the width/height trying to take everything into account, but I just can't seem to get it to re-size correctly and not overlap the other content of the page. So, the [header], [navbar], and [footer] are all fixed position, but the [main] content which includes the [summary] and [photograph] are supposed to be relative?

Comment: I have the [photograph] and [summary] both as float: left; and clear: both; so that they stack on top of each other. I'm still very confused as to what else I am missing.

Comment: It depends on what you're planning to have have happen once the screen height becomes less than the sum of the fixed heights of nav, photograph, summary and footer. something is either going to have to overlap somewhere if you want everything visible on the page or you're going to have to remove the 'bottom: 0;' from the CSS style so it will go off screen and can be viewed by scrolling.

Comment: I want to avoid the scroll bar, but just as you provided the solution for the header (which works great, thanks) I would like a similar effect. So, when the browser window is minimized, the two header portions minimize in size symmetrically. I would to have the same thing for the [main] content which also contains the [photograph] and [summary] portion. As it is right now, the [photograph] stays the same size, but the [summary] immediately begins to cut off. Here is the updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/yf4zuue3/ . Unfortunately JFiddle has a difficult time showing the issue.

Comment: If you change your width and height from fixed to absolute sizing as with the header this will force them to resize with the screen. It would also be worth including fixed sizes for both portions using max-width and max-height CSS attributes.

https://jsfiddle.net/59y97uzv/ just a quick example I drew up. The scroll bar might not completely avoidable considering the layout of the page, but this should help minimise the need to implement it.